# UpdateMany isn't updating the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In user schema, Location is an array of objects with `locations._id` is ObjectId.

This is my user service file.

```
const updatedBy = {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
  "locations._id": { $in: req.body.locationIds },
};
const updatingData = { $set: { "locations.$.status": req.query.status }};
const user = await userDbServices.updateRecords(updatedBy, updatingData);
```

In `req.body.locationIds`, I'm passing an array.

And this one is the user DB service file

```
exports.updateRecords = async function (updateParam, updatingData) {
  return userModel.updateMany(updateParam, updatingData);
};
```

When I hit the API, The first embedded document of location is updated. But the other ones aren't. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected behavior of the [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) identifier, from the docs:

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document

To update multiple elements you want to be using the `$[]` identifier with [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters), like so:

```
userModel.updateMany({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
  "locations._id": { $in: req.body.locationIds },
},
{
  $set: {
    "locations.$[elem].status": req.query.status
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem._id": {
        $in: req.body.locationIds
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LnIU__bdZtr)